# xhtml2pdf image takes up the body width

Tags: css, image, xhtml2pdf

Here is the segment of css:

```
.imgdiv{
  float:left;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
  background-color:yellow;
  width:55px;
  height:68px;
}

.zheader{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px 0px 0px 65px;
}
```

And here is the segment of html

```
<div>
  <div class="imgdiv">
     <!-- <img src="images/redzone.gif"> -->
  </div>
  <div class="zheader">
    <h1>Red Zone = Danger</h1>
    <h2>Everything is RED</h2>
  </div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

I want to have the image floating to the left, and the h1/h2 floating to the right of the image.  The HTML is rendered properly on the browser (Chrome, IE, etc)

Put the HTML thru xhtml2pdf, the imgdiv always takes up the whole parent div width and thus push the h1/h2 down below, regardless the width and height values. Comment out the image, then the pdf looks exactly how I want it to be.

My conclusion is the image must have some effect on how xhtml2pdf renders the image and the div contains the image.
What will be the proper way to handle my situation?

Thanks

Comment: I put the h1/h2 inside the imgdiv hoping that will solve the problem.  It does not.  The image still pushes h1/h2 down below as if there is a <br> after the <img>

Comment: Solved. Tags like h1/h2/h3 always triggers a prepended <br> in xhtml2pdf.  While we tend to move away from <table> and use <div> in designing html, but in xhtml2pdf <div> can create so many problems in laying out blocks in the way we desire.  Best is to stay with the <table> approach in converting html to pdf.